# Custom home screen with notifications

Tags: android, wear-os

We have implemented a custom home screen on android for android wear. When we try to show notifications, it does not show up.
Notification comes up if we are using the default home screen.

Any leads on where we are going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried and made your title a Spannable ? I remember that it did the trick for me back when I struggled with notifications
`String title = "Notification title";
Spannable customTitle = new SpannableString(title);`
And when creating your notification, set the title of your notification with the spannable : 
`setTitle(customTitle)`

Comment: This is an android  wear app. Notifications comes up in form of a card. The card itself is not coming up. The issue is not with the title od the message but the card not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify what you mean by "custom home screen on Android for Android Wear"?

If you are working on creating notification locally on Android Wear that will show up in the notification stream, please take a look at the **SynchronizedNotifications** sample under samples/android-20/wearable/. This sample shows how applications can create different local notifications for mobile and wear and get them to sync.